# How to set properties on a generic entity?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'd like to check if an entity has 3 properties. CreatedDate, ModifiedDate, and ModifiedBy.

Right now I am just hardcoding the ones that I know have them in the SaveChanges() method of my Object Context.

For instance:

```
bool newEntity = (entry.State == EntityState.Added);

if (type == typeof(Foo))
{
  var r = entry.Entity as Foo;
  if (r != null)
  {
    if (newEntity) 
      r.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
    r.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
    r.ModifiedBy = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
  }
}
```

I know it's possible to check if an object has a certain method using code similar to this:

```
public static bool HasMethod(this object objectToCheck, string methodName)
{
    var type = objectToCheck.GetType();
    return type.GetMethod(methodName) != null;
}
```

But how would I get at those properties without directly casting the entity?

How can I do something like:

```
if (HasMethod(entry.Entity))
      entry.Entity.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
```

I am using ASP.Net MVC 4.

Comment: Use reflection. `PropertyInfo`.

Comment: Maybe [dynamic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264736.aspx) can be used for that, but i must say i'm not sure about it.

Comment: There's no point in adding tags in titles. Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19190/147072 for more information.

Comment: Better, if you have access to the declaration of these entities, is to create an interface that includes these properties, assign that interface to all the entities that also include them, and then check if the object implements that interface.

Comment: For things like this I tend to put those properties on a base class that all my database-mapped entities inherit from, so that I know they'll be there. Then you can just add `where T : EntityBase` and access the properties directly from your `Add<T>()` and `Update<T>()` methods. I realise this may not be possible in your case, but it's worth mentioning.

Comment: I looked up PropertyInfo but they still are using a direct type. I'd like to not reference any direct types at all and just check if the entity has the methods and if so set them without casting it to the correct type. The problem is that only certain entities will have these properties, not all of them. My entities are also generated by the Entity Framework.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use below method. It will set the property if it exists. Using `GetType` at each call may cause some overhead, it needs optimization.

```
private bool TrySetProperty(object obj, string property, object value) {
  var prop = obj.GetType().GetProperty(property, BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
  if(prop != null && prop.CanWrite) {
    prop.SetValue(obj, value, null);
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Usage

```
TrySetProperty(entry.Entity, "ModifiedDate", DateTime.Now);
```

Comment: Very nice. I'll benchmark it to see how well it performs. Very clever either way.

Comment: @Smith: The actual lookup of the type and property takes quite some time, but if you manage to cache them in a static dictionary for instance, the efficiency in terms of speed would improve alot.

Comment: (imo) If you are going to prepend "Try" to your method name you should make the return type bool to be consistent with methods like int.TryParse (and many others)

Answer (score 11):

You can either use reflection -- which has been mentioned by several people already -- or you can create an interface. If you are using auto-generated entities, they are defined with the `partial` keyword, so you can create another class file in the same project, and give it the same namespace and class definition, and you can have that implement your interface. Then in the code you posted above, you check to see if the object implements your interface, if so, cast to it, then set the values.

The advantage of the interface is that you aren't using reflection (which can be an expensive operation), and also, any future entities you create will work automatically just by implementing your interface.

In cases where your entity properties don't exactly match your interface, you can explicitly implement the interface, that will handle any naming irregularities.

Example: Let's say you've defined an interface, `IContainAuditProperties`, and you have all your applicable entities implement that interface, you could do the following inside a block where you are looping over all your new/altered entities:

```
var entity = entry.Entity as IContainAuditProperties;
if(entity != null)
{
  entity.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
  entity.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
  //etc.
}
```

Starting with C# 7.0, the above code can be simplified:

```
if(entry.Entity is IContainAuditProperties entity) {
  entity.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
  entity.ModifiedDate = DateTime.Now;
  //etc.
}
```

Comment: I have no problem using partial classes to implement the interface since I already have many anyways for my metadata attributes. My question is how to cast without directly referencing the enity.

Comment: I agree with Brian. Interfaces are definitely the way to go here.

Comment: This should be the top answer. Using reflection is a bad idea unless you prefer slower code and more code.

Comment: +1 for "This should be the accepted answer". Better practices outweigh the most obvious solution (and definitely using reflections) almost always.

Answer (score 1):

You can check if an object has a public settable property with a certain name using this code:

```
public static bool HasWritableProperty(this object objectToCheck, string propertyName)
{
  var type = objectToCheck.GetType();
  //get a property info for the property, but only if it is a public instance property
  var pi = type.GetProperty(propertyName, BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
  //return false if no propery is found
  if (pi==null) return false;
  //get the set method for the property
  var setter = pi.GetSetMethod();
  //if it's null the property is not writable
  return (setter != null);
}
```

However, this is not a very efficient code, as it uses a lot of reflection.

If you go this route, I would memoize the result of this code, so every check will be run at most once.

What I actually do in my projects (I use EF Code First), is have a `BaseEntity` class that has the properties that are common, and have the concrete entities inherit from the `BaseEntity` class. Then I have a `FillEntityMetadata` method, that is more or less this:

```
protected void FillEntityMetadata(BaseEntity entity, bool isUpdate = false)
{
  // Set audit data.
  if (!isUpdate)
  {
    entity.CreatedBy = CurrentUser.ID;
    entity.CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
    entity.IsActive = true;
  }
  entity.LastModifiedBy = CurrentUser.ID;
  entity.LastModifiedOn = DateTime.Now;
}
```

Note that for this to work, you can also use an interface, `IBaseEntity`, and it would function in the same way.